# performance of SAX parser increasing with multiple runs

Tags: java, performance, xml-parsing, sax

I am parsing an XML file using SAX parser(extending DefaultHandler) and can see that parsing time reduces if the same file is parsed multiple times. An example of time taken to parse the same file 5 times is  :

1. TOTAL PARSE TIME IN ms = 257
2. TOTAL PARSE TIME IN ms = 125
3. TOTAL PARSE TIME IN ms = 50
4. TOTAL PARSE TIME IN ms = 62
5. TOTAL PARSE TIME IN ms = 30

The method to parse looks like :

```
        public void deSerialize(String xml){
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            MyParserHandler userhandler = new MyParserHandler();
            saxParser.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("utf-8"))), userhandler);
        }
```

The pattern of reducing time remains the same even if same xml content is read from different files each time.

For each iteration, the method is called. I am using following to measure time

```
      long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
      MyParserHandler.deserializeXML(xml);
      long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
      System.out.println("TOTAL PARSE TIME IN ms = " + (time2-time1));
```

Is there a specific reason for this behaviour?

Comment: How are you measuring the time ? are you building any cache ?

Comment: @svasa I have added details to the question. No cache being used.

Comment: It is interesting, my guess is somehow the parser's scanDocument is optimized from run to run that is causing this improvement in performance

Comment: based on my experience benching xml parsers, you could ascribe the speed up to hotspot JVM's code optimization...